# Designing RC Coupled amplifier from bandwidth

Tags: amplifier, bjt

Is it possible to design an RC Coupled BJT amplifier (finding resistor and capacitor values and constructing the circuit ) if only bandwidth is given? It is possible if cutoff frequency is given, but I am confused if it is possible if only bandwidth is given.

Comment: Low-pass, high-pass, band-pass? 1st, 2nd, ... order? Coupling capacitors give only high-pass which has infinite bandwidth...well, not quite

Comment: You really do need to write more. Just FYI. What you've said just isn't enough. What kind of homework problem is this? Can you provide details about the question?

Comment: Rach, you really ***do*** need to say something here. Respond. Let us know you exist and are really interested. Otherwise, nothing much more can be said, I fear.

Answer (score 2):

If your RC circuit is a low-pass filter, the Bandwidth is going from 0 to fc. fc is your frequency at -3dB.

If you have the Bandwidth, you can know the frequency then.

After that, use [image]

then you can choose either R or C in order to find the other to have the good frequency.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth assumes/requires either a low-, mid- or high-end frequency of the pass band. Usually it’s clear from the application.

Eg. a transmission channel filter in the IF chain has assumed passband around the channel center.

A baseband signal, like audio or a non-modulated transducer output has passband starting at 0Hz unless otherwise given.

In general, it’s worthwhile to specify the low- and high-frequency cutoffs of a passband. Absent that, you need to assume something and write down the motivation for such assumption.

So, to answer your question: no. It’s not possible without knowing what the lower and upper edge frequencies of the passband are. Bandwidth is only the difference between them. In some situations engineering practice informs an assumed lower-, mid- or high-end of the pass band. But you need to have one - whether given explicitly or assumed.